# how to add thumbnails to dots of slick slider mentioning the current slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on a new project which required a slider. I have implemented slick JS for one of my project.

Now I need to add thumbnails which will appear when we hover the dots  which will link to the slider

For example, click on first thumb and slider will advance to first slide,....click on third and slides to third slide.

HTML

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/style.css"/>
      </head>
     <body>
<!-- THis is the slider code  -->
        <div class="center">
          <div><img  alt="slide 2" src="images/img1.jpg"></div>
          <div><img  alt="slide 2" src="images/img2.jpg"></div>
          <div><img  alt="slide 2" src="images/img3.jpg"></div>
          <div><img  alt="slide 2" src="images/img4.jpg"></div>
          <div><img  alt="slide 2" src="images/img5.jpg"></div>
        </div>

       <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script> 

       <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.center').slick({

            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '60px',
            slidesToShow: 1,
            dots: !0,   /* It is for the navigation dots  */
            draggable: !1,
            responsive: [
             {
                 breakpoint: 768,
                 settings: {
                     arrows: false,
                     centerMode: true,
                     centerPadding: '40px',
                     slidesToShow: 1
                 }
             },
            {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    arrows: false,
                    centerMode: true,
                    centerPadding: '40px',
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }
            ]
        });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't exactly know how, but what you can do is add a seperate onmouseover attribute to each dot, which will call the required javascript function. Then in the function get the X,Y coordinates of the mouse pointer and display the thumbnail at that X,Y coordinates.

Comment: see the following link. It's very useful to implement slick concept http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 33):

You may replace dots with custom thumbnails. You would need to add thumbnails somewhere (for example, in a hidden div inside the image slide wrapper. See the code for reference:

```
$('.slideme').slick({
  dots: true,
  customPaging: function(slider, i) { 
    // this example would render "tabs" with titles
    return '<button class="tab">' + $(slider.$slides[i]).find('.slide-title').text() + '</button>';
  },
});
```

You would also need tweak up the native Slick pager css to remove dots and add more space and styles for your thumbnails

Comment: I don't think you need to actually do anything to "remove the dots", see a couple of examples: https://jsfiddle.net/oL5bjae1/ and https://jsfiddle.net/simeydotme/9nm4ctv9/

Comment: Im using this inside of a dynamic carousel, when the slide images are removed, the old thumbnails are not being removed. How do I "clear out" old custom paging when a new custom paging is created? currently facing an accumulation where when the old slides are removed, their thumbnails are not

Answer (score 0):

add a data attribute to the slide like the bellow

```
<div class="slide" data-thumb="{{assets}}/images/image-name.jpg"></div>
```

after that add `customPaging` function inside the script like bellow

```
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: true,
  customPaging: function(slider, i) { 
                    return '<button><span class="thumbImg" style="background-image:url('+$(slider.$slides[i]).data('thumb')+');"></span></button>';
                },
});
```