# How to replace dots with text in slick slider and how to position arrows in slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

Dots:
I want text to be displayed instead of dots in slick slider. When the dot reaches active state, then the style of the text should get changed. 
Arrows:
the position of the arrows is shown in the picture. Here also, the colour of arrow should change when it is in active state.
Help in any form would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948356/how-to-add-thumbnails-to-dots-of-slick-slider-mentioning-the-current-slide